# Does a metaclass-level variable cascade down to the metaclass's instantiated classes's instantiated objects the way a class-level variable does?

Tags: python, metaclass, getattribute, python-descriptors, python-datamodel

I've been intensively consulting the Python docs for descriptors, and I can't wrap my head around some points in it regarding descriptor invocation and the given Python equivalent of `object.__getattribute__()`.

The pure Python equivalent given (see "object_getattribute" in the code below) supposedlly calls **type**'s version of  `__getattribute__()` by calling `getattr()` with the class object supplied as first argument, which results in a call to **type**'s `__getattribute__()`. The problem is, having **type**'s attribute lookup (implememted in `type.__getattribute__()`) involved in the lookup for instance invocation should mess up things as it would bridge into a different line of relation in which classes are objects and metaclasses are the classes. The lookup search carried by `object.__getattribute__()` should terminate when the *MRO* of the class is exhausted (at which point **getattr**() would then be utilized), but calling `__getattribute__()` of **type** would illogically cascade search up to cover the metaclass's dict and possibly get back a similarly-named attribute, which is wrong as metaclasses define classes, not objects.
Here is an example creating a metaclass named "mytype", a base class called "base" that uses the Python equivalent provided at: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#technical-tutorial, and an instance class, "myclass", from "mytype":

```
class mytype(type):
    cls_var = 11

class base:
    def object_getattribute(obj, name):
        null = object()
        objtype = type(obj)
        cls_var = getattr(objtype, name, null)
        descr_get = getattr(type(cls_var), '__get__', null)
        if descr_get is not null:
            if (hasattr(type(cls_var), '__set__') or hasattr(type(cls_var), '__delete__')):
                return descr_get(cls_var, obj, objtype)
        if hasattr(obj, '__dict__') and name in vars(obj):
            return vars(obj [name]
        if descr_get is not null:
            return descr_get(cls_var, obj, objtype)
        if cls_var is not null:
            return cls_var
        raise AttributeError(name)
    
    def __init__(s, v):
        s.core = v

    @property
    def core(s):
        return '-- ' + s._core + ' --'

    @core.setter
    def core(s, v):
        s._core = v

myclass = mytype('myclass', (base, ), {'a':97})

o = myclass('IRON')
```

(Note: I don't know how to add a method definition to a class when creating it throw calling **type**'s **new**(), so I came up with class "base" as means to provide the "object_getattribute()" method from the docs)

Now, if I run:

```
print(o.__getattribute__('cls_var'))
```

Or, more simply:

```
print(o.cls_var
```

I get:

```
...
AttributeError: 'myclass' object has no attribute 'cls_var'

[Program finished]
```

The result is what I would normally expect. The search doesn't look in the metaclass for evaluating names - that's different territory. However, if I use the pure Python equivalent from the docs as follows:

```
print(o.object_getattribute('cls_var'))
```

Then I get:

```
11
```

Which is on **mytype**.

Summary: Is the pure-Python version provided in the docs, wrong?

Comment: Yes, I believe this pure Python version isn't exactly correct.

Comment: Here is an interesting, related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70590552/why-does-getting-a-class-property-from-an-instance-raise-an-attributeerror

Comment: You'll notice, in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8dfe15625e6ea4357a13fec7989a0e6ba2bf1359/Objects/object.c#L1184) it uses: `descr = _PyType_Lookup(tp, name);` which uses this specialized, internal function to look up the attribute on the type: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/35d6540c904ef07b8602ff014e520603f84b5886/Objects/typeobject.c#L3840

Comment: they've fixed the example in the Python docs - perhaps as a result of the problem being spotted in this question.

Answer (score 0):

The example that used to be in the docs was incorrect.

If you look there now - `https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#technical-tutorial` you will see that fetching the name in the class, to check if it is a descriptor, does not use `type(obj).__getattribute__` - instead, they wrote a helper function `find_name_in_mro` which accurately emulates the  mechanism of retrieving an attribute.

When one opens the same URL for an older Python version, say, https://docs.python.org/3.9/howto/descriptor.html#technical-tutorial, you will notice the same code as is pasted in the question - which is, in fact, incorrect.

So, putting it yet in other words so there is a chance it makes things clearer for some eventual reader:
When retrieving an attribute in *any* instance in Python, that instance's `__getattribute__` is called. Usually that will default to `object.__getattribute__`, and what it does is:

1. try to retrieve the object in the class namespace or in any super-class. This search does not use `__getattribute__` on the class - it is  a custom search, that will search for the attribute in the class'`__dict__`, and then in the `__dict__` of all its linearized superclasses (the mro - "method resolution order") up to "object".

   1. If the attribute is found in the class, it is saved for later, and immediatelly checked if it is a "data descriptor": i.e., an object which features either `__set__` or `__del__` in its own class. This lookup is non-recursive and checks directly the (retrieved object's) class `slots` - there is this difference for "non data descriptors" because -descriptors featuring only `__get__`, as these can be shadowed by values set in the instance. Data descritors are never shadowed by values in the instance.
   2. If there is a data-descriptor present, `__get__` is called on the descriptor instance, and its return value is used as the result of `__getattribute__`
2. If the value is not on the class-namespace or super-classes, then Python searches the class's `__dict__` itself. Note that attributes in user defined classes can exist in classes whose instances do not have  a `__dict__`, if `__slots__` is used in the class definition. However, attribute access in `__slots__` itself is performed via a specialized descriptor - so, Python will will use the case 1.1 above for those.
3. If there is an attribute in the instance `__dict__`  that is returned
4. Otherwise, if there is a non-data-descriptor present, `__get__` is called in the descriptor object.This is the case used to retrieve functions in the class which are wrapped into bound-methods (the `.__get__()` method in functions do that).
5. As a last resource, `__getattr__` in the same instance is called - if defined - its return value, or `AttributeError` exception are used as result of `__getattribute__`
6. `AttributeError` is raised.