# override numeric magic method as classmethod

Tags: python, metaclass, class-method, magic-methods

I try to use metaclass to implement numeric magic methods for several classes, then override some of them in the "class instance".

```py
from abc import ABCMeta
class Meta(ABCMeta):
  def __add__(self, other):
    print('meta')

class C(metaclass=Meta):
  @classmethod
  def __add__(cls, other):
    print('C')

C + 3 # meta
C.__add__(3) # C
```

It shows that the `+` operator is directly called with `Meta`'s `__add__`, but `C.__add__` calls `getattr(C, '__add__')` and correctly use the overriden class method.
I've tried several code pieces to confirm that.

```py
class Meta(ABCMeta):
  def call(self):
    print('meta')

class C(metaclass=Meta):
  @classmethod
  def call(cls):
    print('C')

C.call() # C
```

```py
class C:
  @classmethod
  def __add__(cls, other):
    print('C')

C + 3 # TypeError
C.__add__(3) # C
```

I guess something special happends when I "register" my implmentation of `__add__`, so the decorator `@classmethod` does not work.
So, how does python evaluates the expression `C + 3`? If I want to override `__add__` for `C`, is there any solution other than inherit another metaclass from `Meta`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, how does python evaluates the expression C + 3?

What takes place here is that Python's method and attribute search priority are different from ordinary methods (like `call`), and methods that are intended to be called indirectly by the language, through the use of an operator (like `__add__`)

For the later, Python defers directly to the slot in the class of the instance being added. That is: When you use "C" with the `+` operator, its class is "Meta", and `Meta.__add__` is called.

In an ordinary attribute access using the `.` notation (either `C.call` or even `C.__add__`(insteaf of using `+`)), the normal rules for attribute access - which are implemented in `object.__getattribute__` are followed - I've summarized the precedence in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70590552/why-does-getting-a-class-property-from-an-instance-raise-an-attributeerror/70593783#70593783). But in short: for dotted access, the classmethod in the class "instance" is retrieved before the method defined in the  "class'class" (just as would happen for an attribute in the `__dict__` of an "ordinary instance" compared to the same attribute in its class).

As for: "If I want to override `__add__` for C, is there any solution other than inherit another metaclass from Meta?"

The "obvious way" would be to have a separate metaclass for each class you want to implement a "class `__add__`" method to. However, you can write `Meta.__add__` so that it, upon being called, check for the existence of an `__add__` method in the class, and forwards the execution of the opertation to it.

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class Meta(ABCMeta):
    def __add__(cls, other):
        print('meta')
        cls_add = getattr(cls, "__add__", None)
        if not cls_add:
            return NotImplemented    
        # checks for __add__ both as an ordinary and as a classmethod
        if (unbound:= getattr(method, "__func__", None)) is not  None and unbound is __class__.__add__ :
            # getattr returned an __add__ method from the metaclass (this very same method here)
            raise NotImplemented
        if unbound:  # if this is not None, __add__ is a class method
            return method(other)
        return method(cls, other) # __add__ is an ordinary method, and we have to fill the 'self' parameter with cls
```